# Style Css Widgettitle

Tags: css, styles

For some reason I just can't get the styling to change on the class="widgettile". I don't get it ... please visit my site on look at sidebar http://www.curious-howto.com, we scroll down towards the bottom and see the 2 widget on the right side. The title is wrapped in

```
<class="widgettitle">This is title</class="widgettitle">
```

but when I add to my style sheet .widgettile {font-family:Lobster;} ... it doesnt style the class ... I usually don't have any problems styling things ... I just don't understand why this doesnt work ... 
Please any advise would be much appreciated

Comment: What kind of tag you used? It's a totally wrong tag. You have to use for example a `DIV` tag in which you assign the `class="widgettitle"` attribute.

Comment: Please paste some code here in addition to linking out to your website. There are also tools for easier demonstration like http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: yea this is a wordpress site and I didnt code the theme :( just trying to figure it out lol :(

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the class assaigned to anything. This is your html `<class="widgettitle">Most Viewed Posts In The Last 30 Days </class="widgettitle">`

You need to add the class to a tag like so `<h3 class="widgetittle">Title</h3>` '' is invalid and does not exist. 
I see you are usng wordpress so more than likely it is a problem with the function.

```
function widgets_init() {
register_sidebar( array(
    'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h3>',
) );
```

Make sure the function is used properly. The code above will add an h3 around the widget title with a class of widget-title.

Comment: I can't seem to find where this code is located ... I check sidebar.php and here is code but it seems like everything is wrapped in proper code :(

Comment: It will be located in the themes functions.php file

Comment: 'code' <ul class="xoxo">
  <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Primary Sidebar') ) : ?>
   <li class="widgetcontainer clearfix">
    <div class="widgettitle"><?php _e('Welcome to Arras!', 'arras') ?></div>
    <div class="widgetcontent">
    <div class="textwidget">
     <p><?php _e('Arras is a WordPress theme designed  customisable features.', 'arras') ?></p>
    </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="widgetcontainer clearfix">
    <div class="widgettitle"><?php _e('Recent Posts', 'arras') ?></div>

Comment: I added code to functions.php since it wasent in there, but everytime I add it breaks the theme and only blank page loads :(

Comment: The code I provided was generic code. You can do a search in your functions.php fr widget. Which theme are you using?

Comment: the only thing that comes up on search is

Comment: require_once ARRAS_LIB . '/widgets.php';

Comment: If you are using this arras theme https://github.com/zyml/project-ar2/blob/master/functions.php then on line 106 you see the function to call the widgets. Each widget will have its own array.

Comment: I must be using the old version of arras since my functions page look much different ...

Comment: The function may be in the widgets.php